# OSGi console "ls -c": References are bound although there is no provider

Tags: osgi, declarative-services

While debugging service binding issues, I called the command `ls -c` (or equivalent `list -c`) and got the following output for my component:

```
21      Component[
        name = org.example.myproject.repo
        activate = activate
        deactivate = deactivate
        modified =
        configuration-policy = optional
        factory = null
        autoenable = true
        immediate = true
        implementation = org.example.myproject.RepositoryServiceHandler
        state = Unsatisfied
        properties =
        serviceFactory = false
        serviceInterface = null
        references = {
                Reference[name = Repository, interface = org.example.core.repository.api.Repository, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindRepository, unbind = unbindRepository]
                Reference[name = IRepositoryClient, interface = org.example.core.repository.client.RepositoryClient, policy = static, cardinality = 1..1, target = null, bind = bindRepositoryClient, unbind = unbindRepositoryClient]
        }
        located in bundle = org.example.myproject_0.20.1348.3 [30]
]
Dynamic information :
  The component is satisfied
  All component references are satisfied
  Component configurations :
    Configuration properties:
      component.name = org.example.myproject.repo
      component.id = 34
    Instances:
      org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.impl.ComponentInstanceImpl@75b98b5a
        Bound References:
        String[org.example.core.repository.client.RepositoryClient]
                -> org.example.core.repository.client.impl.RepositoryClientImpl@67680c91
        String[org.example.core.repository.api.Repository]
                -> org.example.core.repository.api.impl.RepositoryImpl@1c27ecd6
```

I wanted to find the bundle that provides the interface `org.example.core.repository.client.RepositoryClient` and therefore searched the complete output of `ls -c`. To my surprise, there were no other occurrences (i.e. only the two references in my component).

How is it possible that there is no provider, but the service is still bound? Shouldn't there be a provider component with `serviceInterface = org.example.core.repository.client.RepositoryClient`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the solution myself after a while, but I thought I might still share it here in case others have the same problem.

The reason that I didn't find the service provider is that `ls -c` only lists services registered via declarative services. Instead, the service was registered programmatically, and therefore not listed by `ls -c`.

To search all service providers, the `service` command needs to be used:

```
osgi> services (objectClass=org.example.core.repository.client.RepositoryClient)

{org.example.core.repository.client.RepositoryClient}={service.id=83}
  Registered by bundle: org.example.core.repository.client_1.2.102 [45]
  Bundles using service:
    org.example.myproject_0.20.1348.3 [30]
```